# Artificially augmented dataset and LSTM/RNN network?

Tags: dataset, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

We're using a dataset made from all books from two differents writers for generating new contents through torch-rnn (and tensorflow char-rnn as tests).

Our current dataset is aprox 6MB and I was wondering what could happen if I simply copy paste the datas for doubling the amount of characters feeding the network - from 6MB to 12MB / 24 / (...) 120MB ? - while augmenting the rnn-size and the number of layers according to the new weight of the dataset ? Is it worse trying ? Does the network will have a chance to reach a better perplexity ?

Thank you for your answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **no, it does not make any sense**. Amount of data for ML method is not measured in MB of files stored, but rather in amount of information you provide. Copying existing data does not provide **any** new information, so it does literally nothing. Note, that training of an RNN is not based on processing your data **once**, you do it multiple times - this should show you why duplicating dataset changes nothing (what is a difference between going once through 2 copies of a data and going twice through one copy?)

Data augmentation is a process of providing **new** information, this is why for image processing people would randomly rotate images, crop them etc. as this provides your model with information about what kind of transformations do not affect labeling. Language augmentation is **much** harder, as language has really complex rules, you could for example try to substitute some words with their synonyms, based on wordnet, but this is just a heuristic which might fail badly (as you need to substitute a word in a given meaning, not just every occurence of a word).